# Set new name for football club in c++

Tags: c++, string, replace

My task is to set object of football club and change it's name.

In class:

```
Club(string _name, string _colour) :
        name(_name), colour(_colour) {}
void newName(char* newName)
{
   strcpy(name, newName);
}
```

Main:

```
Klub k1("Manchester", "red");
k2.newName("Arsenal");
```

I get this error:
Error   C2664   'std::string Club::newName(char *)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char [7]' to 'char *'

I included cstring

Comment: Why you don't use `std::string` as argument? `strcpy` will not work with `std::string` type.

Comment: once you are using `std::string` there is no reason to use `char*` for strings

Comment: string newName(char* Name)
 {
  name= Name;
  
 }

Comment: `void newName(std::string n) { name = n;}`

Comment: The string literal `"Arsenal"` you pass to the function is a pointer to const char. That's why the compiler complains.

Answer (score 3):

replace void `newName(char*)` with `void newName(const char*)` if you want to use a string literal as an argument to the function. i would suggest passing a `const std::string&` instead of the `char*`.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly assign to a `std::string` object, but it does not make sense to use `strcpy` on it. And as you can construct a `std::string` from a `char *`, you should just do:

```
...
void newName(const char* newName)
{
   name = std::string(newName);
}
```

In addition, as you never change the input parameter you should make it `const`.

Answer (score 0):

```
string newName(string Name)
    {
        name= Name;
        return name;
        
    }
```

Comment: You should at least declare `Name`  to be `const`. It would allow the compiler to elide one copy.